# How to use Freebase API in a PhoneGap Build app?

Tags: ios, api, key, freebase, phonegap-build

Can someone please explain, how to properly use Freebase API in a PhoneGap Build app? From the Google Developer API console, I understand that you need different API keys for Android and iOS apps? If it is so, then how can I deploy the same PhoneGap Build app using the same freebase API to work on different platforms?

Comment: Where does it say that you need different API keys?

Comment: Here, under Simple API access it has different keys for different platforms. Why is that? http://postimg.org/image/ihd46qfrz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freebase uses simple API access by passing the "Browser key" [as a parameter on each request](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/getting-started#api-keys). The same API key should work regardless of the platform.